# Openshift - Correlation between confimap and pods

Tags: openshift

there's a quick way/oc command to get which deployement use one or more configmap ?

In my case, I need to know which deployment I need to rollout to apply configmap update.

No evidence on dc YAML file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [guide](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/configmaps.html) in OpenShift 3.9

In DeploymentConfig this is the Stanza to pull all environment variables from a ConfigMap.

```
spec:
  containers:
    ...
      envFrom: 
        - configMapRef:
            name: env-config
    ...
```

In might be worth grepping all your deploymentConfigs for the keyword `configMap` in a particular namespace/project to check you've got configMaps attached

```
$ oc get dc -o json -n $(oc project -q) | grep -A2 configMap
                                        "configMapRef": {
                                            "name": "printenv-config"
                                        }
```

Assuming injecting environment variables from configmaps, there might be an easier way of doing this? - but you could also pipe into jq and filter based on the `envFrom` array key being not null

```
oc get dc -o json | jq -r '[.items[] | select(.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[]? != null)]' | jq -c '.[] | {namespace: .metadata.namespace, dcname: .metadata.name, configMap: .spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[].configMapRef.name}'
```

Results in:

```
{"namespace":"aps-env","dcname":"openshift-tasks","configMap":"another-config-map"}
{"namespace":"aps-env","dcname":"printenv","configMap":"printenv-config"}
```

Alternatively you might be mounting your configMap via a volume mount, in which case the Stanza is different, and you'd need to adjust the above accordingly

```
"volumes": [
...
    {
        "configMap": {
            "defaultMode": 420,
            "name": "gogs"
        },
        "name": "config-volume"
    }
...
```

Different Query based on Volume mounted configMap

```
$ oc get dc -o json | jq -r '[.items[] | select(.spec.template.spec.volumes[]?.configMap != null)]' | jq -c '.[] | {dcname: .metadata.name, configMapName: .spec.template.spec.volumes[].configMap.name}' | grep -v null
```

Results in:

```
{"dcname":"gogs","configMapName":"gogs-configmap"}
```